# How to parse JSON response without key using Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm new to swift and this issue is kinda new to me, I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse array of strings/JSON response from the API without key using Alamofire. I only know how to parse JSON Arrays/Objects with keys.

Anyways, this is the response from the API

```
[
"electronics",
"jewelry",
"men's clothing",
"women's clothing"
]
```

What I want here is to store each of the response inside an array.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories") else {
            return
        }
        AF.request(url).responseString { response in
        guard let categories = response.value else {
            return
        }
        
        //What I want here is to store each of the response inside an array.


    }
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: It’s an array of strings, so decode as that, `[String].self`

Comment: This is not a JSON. It is an array of Strings

Comment: @udi Are you sure it's not JSON. That response does indeed look like JSON encoded array of strings to me.

Comment: @udi that is valid json

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for those who helped give me idea. For future reference I'll leave this here

```
    guard let url = URL(string:string: "https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories") else {
        return
    }
    AF.request(url).responseString { response in
        guard let categories = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: response.data!) else{
            return
        }
        
        print("response1: \(categories[1])")
        print("response0: \(categories[0])")
        
    }
```

or

```
AF.request(url).responseDecodable(of: [String].self) { response in
            guard let categories = response.value else {
                return
            }
            print("response1: \(categories[1])")
            print("response0: \(categories[0])")
            
        }
```

OUTPUT

```
response1: jewelry
response0: electronics
```

URL Response

```
[
"electronics",
"jewelery",
"men's clothing",
"women's clothing"
]
```

Comment: You can use `responseDecodable` directly here. `.responseDecodable(of: [String].self)` and not have to handle it yourself.

Comment: can you help me how can I create a model for that URLResponse?