# JSON Array to model using Alamofire

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire

I'm creating a UITableView that will display this response in every cell.
The problem is, I do not know how to parse this response to the model.

Here is the response from the api

```
[
"electronics",
"jewelery",
"men's clothing",
"women's clothing"
]
```

Here is the code for the the ViewController

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var category: [Category] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(Constants.url.baseUrl)\(Constants.url.category)") else {
            return
        }
        
        
        AF.request(url).responseDecodable(of: [Category].self) { response in
            guard let categories = response.value else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            
            
        }

    }

}

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("category count", category.count)

        return category.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.identifiers.categoryTableViewCell) as? CategoryTableViewCell else{
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.configureTableViewCell(with: self.category[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }


}
```

Here is my model

```
struct Category: Codable {
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: As suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969698/how-to-parse-json-response-without-key-using-alamofire) you don't need a model because the JSON is just a string array. Decode `[String].self`

Comment: as mentioned, you are dealing with just an array of strings, the `model` is just `[String]`.
In your code, you can replace `Category` by `String`, or if you are really determined on using the name `Category`, use `typealias Category = String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a model class then decode as already suggested into a String array and then map the result to your model

```
struct Category {
    let name: String
}

AF.request(url).responseDecodable(of: [String].self) { response in
    guard let categories = response.value else {
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self.category = categories.map(Category.init)
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to your problem...

So your model class will look something like this :

```
import Foundation
struct Category: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    }

}
```

Now you can use this as one of the three following ways to parse the data :

1.Using Codable Mapping :

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in  
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let responseModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(Category.self, from: data!)

}
task.resume()
```

2.Using ObjectMapper

```
// Convert JSON String to Model
let responseModel = Mapper<Category>().map(JSONString: JSONString)

// Create JSON String from Model
let JSONString = Mapper().toJSONString(responseModel, prettyPrint: true)
```

3.Using Dictionary Mapping

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    let someDictionaryFromJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
    data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
    let category = Category(someDictionaryFromJSON)

}
task.resume()
```